# How to resize progress bar according to available space?

Tags: bash, shell, resize, progress-bar

I am looking to get an effect where the length of my progress bar resizes accordingly to my PuTTY window. This effect is accomplished with wget's progress bar.

Here is my program I use in my bash scripts to create a progress bar:

_progress_bar

```
#!/bin/bash

maxwidth=50     # line length (in characters)
filled_char="#"
blank_char="."

current=0 max=0 i=0

current=${1:-0} 
max=${2:-100} 

if (( $current > $max )) 
then 
    echo >&2 "current value must be smaller max. value" 
    exit 1 
fi
percent=`awk 'BEGIN{printf("%5.2f", '$current' / '$max' * 100)}'`

chars=($current*$maxwidth)/$max
echo -ne " ["

while (( $i < $maxwidth )) 
do 
    if (( $i <= $chars ));then
        echo -ne $filled_char 
    else
        echo -ne $blank_char
    fi 
    i=($i+1)
done 

echo -ne "] $percent%\r" 


if (( $current == $max )); then
    echo -ne "\r"
    echo
fi
```

Here is an example of how I use it, this example finds all Tor Onion proxies Exit nodes and bans the IP under a custom chain:

```
#!/bin/bash


IPTABLES_TARGET="DROP"
IPTABLES_CHAINNAME="TOR"

WORKING_DIR="/tmp/"

# get IP address of eth0 network interface
IP_ADDRESS=$(ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet addr/ {split ($2,A,":"); print A[2]}')



if ! iptables -L "$IPTABLES_CHAINNAME" -n >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then            #If chain doesn't exist
    iptables -N "$IPTABLES_CHAINNAME" >/dev/null 2>&1               #Create it
fi


cd $WORKING_DIR


wget -q -O - http://proxy.org/tor_blacklist.txt -U NoSuchBrowser/1.0 > temp_tor_list1
sed -i 's|RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} \^||g' temp_tor_list1
sed -i 's|\$.*$||g' temp_tor_list1
sed -i 's|\\||g' temp_tor_list1
sed -i 's|Rewrite.*$||g' temp_tor_list1

wget -q -O - "https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=$IP_ADDRESS&port=80" -U NoSuchBrowser/1.0 > temp_tor_list2
wget -q -O - "https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=$IP_ADDRESS&port=9998" -U NoSuchBrowser/1.0 >> temp_tor_list2
sed -i 's|^#.*$||g' temp_tor_list2



iptables -F "$IPTABLES_CHAINNAME"


CMD=$(cat temp_tor_list1 temp_tor_list2 | uniq | sort)
UBOUND=$(echo "$CMD" | grep -cve '^\s*$')

for IP in $CMD; do
    let COUNT=COUNT+1
    _progress_bar $COUNT $UBOUND
    iptables -A "$IPTABLES_CHAINNAME" -s $IP -j $IPTABLES_TARGET
done

iptables -A "$IPTABLES_CHAINNAME" -j RETURN


rm temp_tor*
```

Edit:

I realized that first example people may not want to use so here is a more simple concept:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..100}; do
    _progress_bar $i 100
done
```

Comment: Do you know that sequence of `sed` commands can be combined? `sed 's ...; s ...; s ...' filename` or `sed -e 's ...' -e 's ...' -e 's ...' filename` and the `wget` can be piped into it? `wget ... | sed ... > filename` (you can use a pipe for the second set, too: `{ wget ...; wget ...; } | sed ... > filename`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes to your script:

- Converted it to a function. If you want to keep it in a separate file so it's available to multiple scripts, just source the file in each of your scripts. Doing this eliminates the overhead of repeatedly calling an external script.
- Eliminated the while loop (which should have been a `for ((i=0; $i < $maxwidth; i++))` loop anyway) for a drastic speed-up.
- Changed your arithmetic expressions so they evaluate immediately instead of setting them to strings for later evaluation.
- Removed dollar signs from variable names where they appear in arithmetic contexts.
- Changed `echo -en` to `printf`.
- Made a few other changes
- Changed the AWK output so "100.00%" is decimal aligned with smaller values.
- Changed the AWK command to use variable passing instead of "inside-out: quoting.

Here is the result:

```
_progress_bar () {
    local maxwidth=50     # line length (in characters)
    local filled_char="#"
    local blank_char="."

    local current=0 max=0 i=0
    local complete remain

    current=${1:-0}
    max=${2:-100}

    if (( current > max ))
    then
        echo >&2 "current value must be smaller than max. value"
        return 1
    fi
    percent=$(awk -v "c=$current" -v "m=$max" 'BEGIN{printf("%6.2f", c / m * 100)}')

    (( chars = current * maxwidth / max))

    # sprintf n zeros into the var named as the arg to -v
    printf -v complete '%0*.*d' '' "$chars" ''
    printf -v remain '%0*.*d' '' "$((maxwidth - chars))" ''

    # replace the zeros with the desired char
    complete=${complete//0/"$filled_char"}
    remain=${remain//0/"$blank_char"}

    printf ' [%s%s] %s%%\r' "$complete" "$remain" "$percent"
}
```

What was the question? Oh, see [BashFAQ/091](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/091). Use `tput` or `bash -i` and `$COLUMNS`. If you use `bash -i`, however, be aware that it will have the overhead of processing your startup files

Comment: You sir, are a god. It's actually fast now.

Comment: @BHare: By the way, do you know about [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml)?

Answer (score 1):

After some google searching I did find the following:

`tput cols` will return the amount of columns, much like Sdaz's suggested `COLUMNS` var.

Therefore I am going with:
`maxwidth=$(tput cols)` unless someone else has a more bulletproof way without requiring `tput`

Answer (score 0):

Bash exports the `LINES` and `COLUMNS` envvars to the window rows and column counts, respectively.  Furthermore, when you resize the putty window, via the SSH or telnet protocols, there is sufficient logic in the protocol to send a `WINCH` signal to the active shell, which then resets these values to the new window dimensions.

In your bash script, use the `COLUMNS` variable to set the current dimensions, and divide `100 / progbarlen` (progbarlen based on a portion of the COLUMNS variable) to get how many percentage points make up one character, and advance them as your progress moves along.  To handle the resizing dynamically, add a handler for `SIGWINCH` (via `trap`) and have it reread the `COLUMNS` envvar, and redraw the progress bar using the new dimensions.

(I haven't tested this in a shell script, and there may be some additional logic required, but this is how bash detects/handles resizing.)

Comment: $COLUMNS seems to have no value in the bash script, however from the terminal echo $COLUMNS seems to work.

Comment: Ah, you are correct.  Your solution above with `tput` looks good, and seems to be updated upon resize, as well.